# R: aggregation (median) of data.frame rows from >2 columns

Tags: r

I would like to aggregate my data.frame.

Here is sample data:

```
data <- structure(list(Charge = c(210133L, 210133L, 210133L, 210152L, 
                                  210152L, 210152L, 210152L, 210180L, 210180L, 210180L), Seq = c(1L, 
                                                                                                       2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L), x = c(NA, 1.5, 2, 
                                                                                                                                                         1.5, 1, 0.67, 1.17, 1, 1, 1), y = c(0.5, 0.5, 1, NA, 0.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)), .Names = c("Charge", "Seq", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

*for explanation (same data as above, different format):

```
   Charge Seq    x   y
1  210133   1   NA 0.5
2  210133   2 1.50 0.5
3  210133   3 2.00 1.0
4  210152   1 1.50  NA
5  210152   2 1.00 0.5
6  210152   3 0.67 0.5
7  210152   4 1.17 0.5
8  210180   1 1.00 0.5
9  210180   2 1.00 0.5
10 210180   2 1.00 0.5
```

Median of x and y column rows has to be performed for the Seq >1 for each unique Charge.

So for example for this sample data, i would like to obtain is additional row with x and y rows median for seq>1:

```
       Charge Seq    x   y
    1  210133   1   NA 0.5
    2  210133   2 1.50 0.5
    3  210133   3 2.00 1.0
    4  210133   >1 1.75 0.75 #here is additional row with median of x and y
    4  210152   1 1.50  NA
    5  210152   2 1.00 0.5...
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), Grouped by "Charge", loop over the column (`lapply(.SD,...`), get the `median` of the columns specified in `.SDcols` based on the condition in 'i' (`Seq >1`), create a 'Seq' column with value ">1".  Place the original data along with the new in a `list`, use `rbind` to combine the datasets, and `order` if necessary.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
res <- data[Seq > 1L, lapply(.SD, median, na.rm=TRUE), 
            by = Charge, .SDcols = x:y][, Seq := ">1"][]
ans <- setorder(rbind(data, res), Charge, Seq)
#    Charge Seq    x    y
# 1: 210133   1   NA 0.50
# 2: 210133   2 1.50 0.50
# 3: 210133   3 2.00 1.00
# 4: 210133  >1 1.75 0.75
# 5: 210152   1 1.50   NA
# 6: 210152   2 1.00 0.50
# 7: 210152   3 0.67 0.50
# 8: 210152   4 1.17 0.50
# 9: 210152  >1 1.00 0.50
#10: 210180   1 1.00 0.50
#11: 210180   2 1.00 0.50
#12: 210180   2 1.00 0.50
#13: 210180  >1 1.00 0.50
```

---

A similar option using `dplyr` where we convert the `class` of "Seq" to `character` in the original dataset.  Then, `filter` for "Seq" not equal to 1, grouped by "Charge", we get the `median` of the columns with `summarise_each`, create a new column in the output "Seq", then bind the original data with the new one using `bind_rows`, and `order` if necessary.

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
data %<>%
     mutate(Seq = as.character(Seq))

data %>% 
   filter(Seq!="1") %>%
   group_by(Charge) %>% 
   summarise_each(funs(median=median(., na.rm=TRUE)), x:y) %>%
   mutate(Seq = ">1") %>% 
   bind_rows(data, .) %>% 
   mutate(Seq = factor(Seq, levels = c(unique(data$Seq), ">1"))) %>% 
   arrange(Charge, Seq)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing the same using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)

test <- function(x){
    seq.gt.1 <- which(x$Seq > 1)

    median.1 <- median(x$x[seq.gt.1],na.rm=T)
    median.2 <- median(x$y[seq.gt.1],na.rm=T)

    return (rbind(x,data.table(Seq='>1',x=median.1,y=median.2)))
}

data[,test(.SD),by=Charge]

 ##   Charge Seq    x    y
 ##1: 210133   1   NA 0.50
 ##2: 210133   2 1.50 0.50
 ##3: 210133   3 2.00 1.00
 ##4: 210133  >1 1.75 0.75
 ##5: 210152   1 1.50   NA
 ##6: 210152   2 1.00 0.50
 ##7: 210152   3 0.67 0.50
 ##8: 210152   4 1.17 0.50
 ##9: 210152  >1 1.00 0.50
##10: 210180   1 1.00 0.50
##11: 210180   2 1.00 0.50
##12: 210180   2 1.00 0.50
##13: 210180  >1 1.00 0.50
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!Your code works as well perfectly